# Setup "Stackdriver Kubernetes Monitoring" for AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, server-monitoring

Google Cloud Platform announced "Stackdriver Kubernetes Monitoring" at Kubecon 2018. It looks awesome.

I am an AWS user running a few Kubernetes clusters and immediately had envy, until I saw that it also supported AWS and "on prem".

[Stackdriver Kubernetes Engine Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-monitoring)

This is where I am getting a bit lost.

1. I cannot find any documentation for helping me deploy the agents onto my Kubernetes clusters. The closest example I could find was here: [Manual installation of Stackdriver support](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/kubernetes-engine/customizing), but the agents are polling for "internal" GCP metadata services.

   ```
   E0512 05:14:12 7f47b6ff5700 environment.cc:100 Exception: Host not found (authoritative): 'http://metadata.google.internal./computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/cluster-name'
   ```
2. I'm not sure the Stackdriver dashboard has "Stackdriver Kubernetes Monitoring" turned on. I don't seem to have the same interface as the demo on YouTube [here](https://youtu.be/aa8cgmfHTAs?t=4m25s)

I'm not sure if this is something which will get turned on when I configure the agents correctly, or something I'm missing.

I think I might be missing some "getting started" documentation which takes me through the setup.

Comment: Why the downvote? The OP has done his homework and the questions are valid (as of today)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Stackdriver partner service, Blue Medora BindPlane, to monitor AWS Kubernetes or almost anything else in AWS for that matter or on-premise.  Here's an article from Google Docs about the partnership: *[About Blue Medora](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/blue-medora)*; you can signup for BindPlane through the [Google Cloud Platform Marketplace](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/bluemedora/bindplane).

It looks like BindPlane is handling deprecated Stackdriver monitoring agents. *[Google Cloud: Transition guide for deprecated third-party integrations](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/plugins/bindplane-transition)*

Answer (score 0):

As per this [article](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/kubernetes-engine/), currently Stackdriver Kubernetes Monitoring beta release only supports Kubernetes version v1.10.2 clusters running on Google Cloud Platform's Kubernetes Engine. To track when this feature will be available in AWS, I suggest creating a feature request in [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com).

Comment: Bit of a shame given the frontpage says "Easy to get started on any cloud or on-prem". https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-monitoring

Answer (score 0):

Stackdriver monitoring of Amazon EKS, Azure AKS, and general purpose Kubernetes running on non--GCP hosted VMs is available if you enable the BindPlane option for Stackdriver.

https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/blue-medora