# How to Send On Premises Kubernetes Logs to Stackdriver

Tags: kubernetes, fluentd, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

**Objective**: Get some logging/monitoring on Googles
Stackdriver from a Kuberntes HA cluster
that is on premises, version 1.11.2.

I have been able to send logs to Elasticsearch using [Fluentd Daemonset for
Kubernetes](https://github.com/fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset), but the
project is not supporting Stackdriver
([issue](https://github.com/fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset/issues/6)).
That said, there is a docker image created for Stackdriver
([source](https://github.com/fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset/tree/master/docker-image/v1.2/debian-stackdriver)),
but it does not have the daemonset.  Looking at other daemonsets in this
repository, there are similarities between the different `fluent.conf` files
with the exception of the Stackdriver `fluent.conf` file that is missing any
environment variables.

As noted in the [GitHub
issue](https://github.com/fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset/issues/6)
mentioned above there is a plugin located in the Kubernetes GitHub
[here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/),
but it is legacy.
The docs can be found
[here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/logging-stackdriver/).

It states:

> "Warning: The Stackdriver logging daemon has known issues on
>   platforms other than Google Kubernetes Engine. Proceed at your own risk."

Installing in this manner fails, without indication of why.

Some other notes. There is [Stackdriver Kubernetes
Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-monitoring/) that clearly
states:

> "Easy to get started on any cloud or on-prem"

on the front page, but
doesn't seem to explain how. This [Stack Overflow
question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50303093/setup-stackdriver-kubernetes-monitoring-for-aws)
has someone looking to add the monitoring to his AWS cluster. It seems that it is not yet supported.

Furthermore, on the actual Google
Stackdriver it is also stated that

> "Works with multiple clouds and on-premises infrastructure".

Of note, I am new to Fluentd and the Google Cloud Platform, but am pretty
familiar with administering an on-premise Kubernetes cluster.

Has anyone been able to get monitoring or logging to work on GCP from another platform? If so, what method was used?

Comment: AFAIK this is the official solution: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/fluentd-gcp.  I would focus on figuring out what errors you see when you install it on your cluster

Comment: I was afraid so. Thanks for the help on editing. Ill update if I am able to get this working.

Answer (score 2):

Consider reviewing [this documentation](https://docs.bindplane.bluemedora.com/docs/kubernetes-1) for using the BindPlane managed fluentd service from Google partner Blue Medora. It is available in Alpha to all Stackdriver users. It parses/forwards Kubernetes logs to Stackdriver, with additional payload markup. 
*Disclaimer: I am employed by Blue Medora.*

Answer (score 0):

Check out the new Stackdriver BindPlane integration which provides on-premise log capabilities.

It is fully supported by Google and is free (other than typical Stackdriver consumption fees)

https://cloud.google.com/solutions/logging-on-premises-resources-with-stackdriver-and-blue-medora